# ViewBag dynamic Url.Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, dynamic-html

All I want to replace code handy `Url.Content` instead of using `ViewBag`. How could I do that?

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/")">Home</a>
   <ul>
       <li>
           <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/Categories/1?name=Mountain Bikes&class=image")">Mountain Bikes</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/Categories/2?name=Road Bikes&class=image")">Road Bikes</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/Categories/3?name=Touring Bikes&class=image")">Touring Bikes</a>
       </li>

   </ul>
```

ViewBag:

```
 ViewBag.Menu = BikesDB.ProductSubcategories
                .Where(m => m.isSelected == true).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(p => new Bike { 
                                        Id = p.ProductSubcategoryID,
                                        Name = p.NameofBike 
                         });
```

Comment: can you please give some more information about what you want?

Comment: ... an example, for instance. It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to use the `ViewBag` or the `Url.Content` helper?

Comment: `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/"+ViewBag.ThemeName+"/images/logo.png")" alt="logo"/>` something like this. I want to use the `ViewBag` in `Url.Content` replace for `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Following for that ::

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/")">Home</a>
<ul>


    @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Menu)
    {
       <li>
          <a href="@Url.Content("~/Bike/Categories/"+item.ID+"?name="+item.Name+"&class=image")">@item.Name</a>
       </li>   
    }

</ul>
```

Because the ViewBag you have made contains multiple Entries(i.e. Enumerable)

```
ViewBag.Menu = BikesDB.ProductSubcategories
                .Where(m => m.isSelected == true).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(p => new Bike { 
                                        Id = p.ProductSubcategoryID,
                                        Name = p.NameofBike 
                         });
```

Comment: why SO still doesn't support RAZOR syntax...?